# How to show cached images while downloading new with Glide and signature

Tags: java, android, android-glide, image-loading

I am using the following method to refresh my thumbnails daily. The url is holding images which change every few minutes, but im okay with thumbnails on daily basis.

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .signature(currentTimeInMilis)
    .thumbnail(Glide.with(this)
        .load(url)
        .signature(dailySignatureWithInternetConnection)
    )
    .into(imageView);
```

It works well in case that is the same date or the date changes while the device is without an internet connection. In thoose cases glide shows immediately cached thumbnails and downloads new (case with internet connection) because of the first signature (currentTimeInMilis).

My problem comes when the thumbnail signature changes (next day with internet connection). None of my thumbnails is showing while the new images are being downloaded from the internet!

I would like to have cached images shown while new images are being downloaded, then it can refresh the image and update the cache. Is such an approach possible with glide?

Comment: There's a callback that might suits your use cases, e.g: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#cache-invalidation

Comment: I'm not quite sure which callback you mean. Could you indicate which function / callback could solve my problem, and what's the approach?

Comment: how about adding this to your thumbnail? https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#loading-only-from-cache

Comment: Thanks, I will try this method the next days after I return to Android studio :)